# lstlisting basicstyle with color and fontsize

Tags: color, lyx, fontsize, lstlisting

I have a setting of lstlisting as shown below. I would like to change to font size of the listing. I know that I can do that with `basicstyle=\tiny` or similar, but that loses the `basicstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily`. I have tried combinations of `basicstyle=\tiny\color{white}\ttfamily` and `basicstyle=\color{white}\tiny\ttfamily`, but to no effect. How do I get tiny white text?

```
\lstset{
 backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
 tabsize=4,
 language=C++,
 captionpos=b,
 frame=l,
 framesep=4.5mm,
 framexleftmargin=1.5mm,
 numbers=left,
 numberstyle=\tiny\color{white},
 numbersep=5pt,
 breaklines=true,
 morekeywords={constexpr},
 showstringspaces=false,
 emph={int,char,double,float,unsigned,void,bool},
 emphstyle={\color{type}},
 basicstyle=\footnotesize,
 identifierstyle=\color{idColor}\ttfamily,
 basicstyle=\color{white}\ttfamily,
 keywordstyle=\color{keyword}\ttfamily,
 stringstyle=\color{stringColor}\ttfamily,
 commentstyle=\color{comment}\ttfamily,
 otherkeywords={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0},
 morekeywords=[2]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0},
keywordstyle=[2]{\color{numberColor}},
}
```

Comment: `basicstyle=\tiny\color{white}\ttfamily,` works fine for me. Show  a complete example.